# Why are these two ways of writing a jQuery plugin equivalents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Why are these two ways of writing a jQuery plugin  equivalents?

---

First way:

```
$.fn.myplugin = function () {
    return $(this).each(function() {
        return $(this).bind('click', function () {
            console.log('Hi');
        });
    });
};
```

---

Second way:

```
$.fn.myplugin = function () {
    return this.bind('click', function () {
        console.log('Hi2');
    });
};
```

Comment: You're probably wondering why the second works in cases where the stack of elements contains multiple matched elements. Internally, jQuery calls whatever methods are stipulated in the chain on ALL matched elements. In other words, the iteration is still done, but internally.

Comment: Hint: **Use the second one.**

Comment: @minitech: Why? A real plugin will most likely do more than just binding an event. And then it might be much better to have a separate scope for each element from the collection. However, in **this specific case** you are right.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: There you go - this specific case :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's reduce from one to the other:

```
$.fn.myplugin = function () {
    return $(this).each(function() {
        return $(this).bind('click', function () {
            console.log('Hi');
        });
    });
};
```

When you start your function `this` is a jQuery object, so `$(this)` doesn't buy you anything, it could easily become:

```
$.fn.myplugin = function () {
    return this.each(function() {
        return $(this).bind('click', function () {
            console.log('Hi');
        });
    });
};
```

So you are saying "For each element in the jQuery object, create a jQuery object and bind an event to that object."

If you look in `bind`, it calls `on`, which performs some logic and finally does this line:

```
return this.each( function() {
    jQuery.event.add( this, types, fn, data, selector );
});
```

That means it is going to apply the event to every element in that jQuery object, so you are actually saying:

So you are saying "For each element in the jQuery object, create a jQuery object, and **for every element in that jQuery object** bind an event to that element."

You are now looping twice, once in a list of `N` elements and then `N` times in lists of 1 element.  You can actually just all bind directly:

```
$.fn.myplugin = function () {
    return this.bind('click', function () {
        console.log('Hi2');
    });
};
```

And that of course, is the final code.

Answer (score 3):

In your case there is no real difference except the fact that you create a new jQuery object in your first snippet for no good reason (`this` is a jQuery object, so no need to use `$(this)`).

Generally spoken it's a good idea to use `return this.each(...);` in your plugin function to keep everything chainable and make your code work no matter how many elements there are in the jQuery object on which your plugin's function was called.

Returning `this.bind(...)` also keeps chainability but for a more complex plugin that does not only just bind an event things are often more readable with the `each` loop.

Comment: returning `this.each` and `this.bind` both keep chaining intact.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference at all between the two.

Just for some reason in one of them you are doing a loop, but in the end, they have the same result.

Comment: There may not be a difference in the result, but the two are **not** equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

They are equivalent because in a jQuery plugin, `this` is the jQuery object, so doing `$(this)` does nothing.

`.bind` will work on all elements in a jQuery object, and when you do `.each` you are calling `.bind` on each element individually.

So, they are equivalent, because they both loop over elements and bind events to them.

I suggest using the 2nd one, it's cleaner and faster.